# Select parent records where ALL children records have a specific status

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

There is table A with records-parents.
In table B are records-children for records from table A, the relationship between them by parent ID.
Children can have the status "open" or "closed". 
A parent can have multiple children in table B.

How to display records from table A that have all children in table B closed? Otherwise do not display

Comment: Does a parent always children?

Comment: please provide table data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check that no not-closed record exists using NOT EXISTS query:

```
SELECT *
FROM TableA
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM TableB
    WHERE TableB.ParentID = TableA.ID
    AND TableB.Status <> 'closed'
)
```

Comment: I had almost forgot [EXIST](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_exists.asp), this is the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this should do it:

```
select a.id
from tablea a
join tableb b on 
  a.id = b.parentid
group by a.id
having count(*) = sum(case when b.status = 'closed' then 1 else 0 end)
```

The key in this solution is to compare if count of records found for particular parent equals count of records for the same parent with status `closed`.

Comment: Should it be count(*) or count(b.*) ?

Comment: Doesn't matter, since there's an inner join between these tables.

Answer (score 1):

This will return a parent if there's no child record (which might be wrong):

```
SELECT *
FROM tabA AS A
WHERE NOT EXISTS
 (
   SELECT * 
   FROM tabB AS B
   WHERE b.Parent = a.id
     AND b.status <> 'closed'
 )
```

This returns a parent if there're child records and all are 'closed':

```
SELECT *
FROM tabA
WHERE id IN
 (
   SELECT Parent
   FROM tabB
   GROUP BY Parent
   HAVING Max(CASE WHEN status = 'closed' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) = 0
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query-

```
Select A.* from A join B on A.ID=B.parentID
where B.status='closed'
```

SQL Server 2014

Comment: this will display A records that have B children open

Comment: It will show A records that have B children closed.As you asked for in your question

Comment: "How to display records from table A that have *all* children in table B closed? Otherwise do not display"

This is joining table A with B, but only B records that have status closed. But, if an A record has B children open and closed, it will be in query result

Answer (score 0):

You can use join to achieve this

```
SELECT * FROM Table_A INNER JOIN Table_B on Table_A.Id = Table_B.ParentId WHERE 
Table_B.Status='closed';
```